# Convert Spark Dataframe Column with Seq of String to Nested Json with Dynamic Json Schema

Tags: java, json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a problem statement where in,I have to create a nested json which will be stored in redis and then served to ui via rest service where it will be used to plot sunburst chart.

***Json example attached below***

Issue with creating nested json is that,for a json object (**where category is cat_a**) inside given json array I can have depth with size **n** which is not known before hand and for the same key (**children in my case**) in different json object (**where category is cat_b**) of the array the depth could be **m**.

My Dataframe looks like following.

```
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
|Category        |EventSeq        |Count           |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
|cat_a           |[A]             |30              |
|cat_a           |[A,B]           |20              |
|cat_a           |[A,B,C]         |5               |
|cat_a           |[A,W]           |4               |
|cat_a           |[C]             |30              |
|cat_a           |[C,A]           |20              |
|cat_a           |[C,A,B]         |5               |
|cat_b           |[X]             |30              |
|cat_b           |[X,Y]           |20              |
|cat_b           |[X,Y,Z]         |5               |
|cat_b           |[Z]             |30              |
|cat_b           |[Z,X]           |20              |
+----------------+----------------+----------------+
```

Now I want to convert this dataframe to Nested Json as follows:

```
[
   {
      "category":"cat_a",
      "children":[
         {
            "name":"A",
            "count":30,
            "children":[
               {
                  "name":"B",
                  "count":20,
                  "children":[
                     {
                        "name":"C",
                        "count":5
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "name":"W",
                  "count":4
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "name":"C",
            "count":30,
            "children":[
               {
                  "name":"A",
                  "count":20,
                  "children":[
                     {
                        "name":"B",
                        "count":5
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "category":"cat_b",
      "children":[
         {
            "name":"X",
            "count":30,
            "children":[
               {
                  "name":"Y",
                  "count":20,
                  "children":[
                     {
                        "name":"Z",
                        "count":5
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "name":"Z",
            "count":30,
            "children":[
               {
                  "name":"X",
                  "count":20
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I don't know if it is even possible in spark with scala or not.
If not then could it be done in Rest Service layer?

Comment: spark version ??

Comment: what about this `|cat_a           |[A,W]           |4               |` data, it is not available in your sample json ?

Comment: @Srinivas spark version 2.4.[A,W] is represented as A  having a child W parallel to B

Answer (score 0):

In Lettuce redis when we get the data corresponding to the key there is a command

```
template.opsForZSet().reverseRangeByScore(K key, double min, double max);
```

so you can achieve using that

Comment: This is not a redis issue.It is more of a issue on how to convert given spark dataframe to Json.